# How does accessing the database on phpmyadmin work?

Tags: database, phpmyadmin

The goal is to have people from anywhere be able to request a change(addition) to the information on the data base. 
I am extremely new to databases and phpmyadmin.
I am just trying to learn how it works.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want other people to be able to change the data in Database , you will have to know some PHP(for communicating with database) and learn how to use it with HTML(for displaying the data or any other content, such as Text Fields,Submit Button etc).

Here is a code example that is used to access the Database.

```
<html>
<head>
<title> Connecting to Database </title>
<?php

$connection=mysql_connect("localhost","username","password","database name");

?>

</head>

<body>
Write whatever you want Here.....

<?php
mysql_close($connection);
?>

</body>

</html>
```

### For Connecting to the Database

```
<?php

$connection=mysql_connect("localhost","username","password","database name");

?>
```

### Closing the Connection

```
<?php
mysql_close($connection);
?>
```

Long and Short, go learn PHP,HTML and some common SQL queries.